# adding characters to a bash variable

Tags: bash, echo, imagick, cat, tr

I got the following code:

```
color=`convert "${WPCURRENT}" -gravity east -crop 20%x100% -resize 1X1 -negate txt:- | tail -n1 |cut -d' ' -f4 | tr -d \#`

echo -n 'color = '$color''  > ~/.config/openbox/wallchange/color.txt
cat ~/.config/openbox/wallchange/color.txt
```

It outputs a hex color code

```
color = CC9ED2
```

Problem is that i require it to be like this:

```
color = 'CC9ED2',
```

How to do that? I already tried creating another variable and place the extra characters to no avail.

Comment: Please try: `echo -n "color = '$color'"`

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a single-quote in the single-quoted string. You can put it in a double-quoted string, and you should use double-quotes anyway, because variable references that aren't in double-quotes sometimes get parsed weirdly. So use this:

```
echo -n "color = '$color',"
```

Note that the double-quotes are shell syntax (telling the shell how to parse what's in them), but the single-quotes are just literal characters as far as the shell is concerned.

(You could also put the single-quotes in an unquoted section, and escape them with backslashes, like `echo -n color = \'$color\',`. But as I said, you want double-quotes for the variable, and you might as well use them on the single-quotes as well.)

But I have a couple of other recommendations: `echo -n` isn't portable, or even reliable. Some versions of `echo` just print "-n" literally as part of their output. I once had a bunch of my scripts break because an OS update changed `echo`'s behavior, and suddenly they were printing "-n" rather than what they were supposed to do. To print things without a newline at the end, use `printf` instead of `echo`. Unfortunately, `printf` is more complicated to use correctly: its first argument is a "format string" that tells it how to print the rest of the arguments. Either of these would work:

```
printf '%s' "color = '$color',"
# or...
printf "color = '%s'," "$color"
```

I'd also recommend using `$( )` instead of backticks to capture the output of a command (see [BashFAQ #82](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)):

```
color=$(convert "${WPCURRENT}" -gravity east -crop 20%x100% -resize 1X1 -negate txt:- | tail -n1 |cut -d' ' -f4 | tr -d \#)
```